# The order and structure of "it makes possible" in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

I was baffled by this sentence

> Such a degree of preparedness, and the rapid deployment of doses it would make possible, could save many lives.

I have no idea of what role "it would make possible" plays in the sentence.
Is there inversion involved in the sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It** (that is, a high degree of preparedness) would make *a rapid deployment of doses* possible.

The sentence could have been written as *...which it would make possible.*

Comment: Kate, thanks for your quick answer. so the whole sentence can be converted into " Such a degree of preparedness would make a rapid deployment of doses possible, could save many lives.  am I right?

Comment: but I think (Such a degree of preparedness), and (the rapid deployment of doses) are both subjects in this sentecnce.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the commas in this sentence, you will see that they mark an aside:

> *, and the rapid deployment of doses it would make possible,*

without which the rest of the sentence can stand on its own:

> Such a degree of preparedness could save many lives.

As Kate correctly pointed out, the aside contains a [reduced relative clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107#:%7E:text=Reduced%20relative%20clauses%20refer%20to,as%20adjective%20clauses%2C%20modify%20nouns.) (*[which] it would make possible*). The aside gives an extra information about the subject, and the sentence practically means:

> Such a degree of preparedness, ***and that includes*** the rapid deployment of doses it would make possible, could save many lives.

There is no subject verb inversion in this sentence.

Comment: Thanks so much, Fev. so there is only one subject "Such a degree of preparedness" in this sentence. "the rapid deployment of doses it would make possible" is an aside giving more information about subject. Am i right?

Comment: Exactly. The aside gives supplementary information. It is non-restrictive, meaning that it does not limit the meaning of the subject in any may, it just brings a detail in.

Comment: I really appreciated it. Fev. if "and the rapid deployment of doses it would make possible" is an aside as a sentence, what does "it" mean in this sentence, and what does "it" represent?

Comment: Kate has already answered this question. It replaces "such a degree of preparedness".

Comment: Thanks so much, Fev, give you a thumbs up. Have a good day.